# Expression Encoder SDK with c#, how to cut video, audio

Tags: c#, .net

How Can I cut video or audio using Expression Encoder SDK with .net?

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/is/encoder/thread/66630b01-2405-41e4-a695-56e45f4596cb) is something that might be helpful to you:

```
// Create a media item and get a pointer to the inital source.
MediaItem item = new MediaItem(@"c:\users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv");
Source source = item.Sources[0];

// Change the first clip so that instead of spanning the entire file
// I'm just going to encode the bit from 5 to 10 seconds.
source.Clips[0].StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
source.Clips[0].EndTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

// Also add the bit from 20 to 30 seconds from the original file.
TimeSpan secondClipStart = new TimeSpan(0,0,20);
TimeSpan secondClipEnd = new TimeSpan(0,0,30);
source.Clips.Add(new Clip(secondClipStart, secondClipEnd));
```

Other than that, I think you are using the wrong tool.